# C# Xamarin Android Update application from APK File

Tags: android, xamarin, apk

I am developing a Xamarin Android application that needs to update itself when I click on a button.

The download is successful, and I find myself with a file (.apk) in the download folder of my device.

Then I need to execute the file.

When I'm in debug mode, the app tells me I need permission to install from the source.
Then I receive the message to start the update.
Finally, I receive the message "The application was not installed because the package conflicts with an already existing package."

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68985243/xamarin-update-existing-app-from-within-the-app-without-any-services-app-not) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959890/android-app-not-install-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-with-a-conflicting) why.

So, I compile the app in V1, then I upload the app in V2 on the drive.
I install V1 on my device, click on the Update button, then it downloads the file and does not update.
It doesn't even show me the messages I have in debug.

Here's my code:

In the AndroidManifest.xlm I have :

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.companyname.bingowmc.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

And:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXTRA_INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXTRA_ALLOW_REPLACE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
```

I have a provider_path.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!--external-path name="external_files" path="." />-->
  <external-path name="external" path="." />
  <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
  <files-path name="files" path="." />
</paths>
```

And there's the c# code :

```
private async Task InstallApk(IDownloadFile file)
        {
            try
            {
                string destinationPath = GetLocalDownloadPathFromFileName("BingoWMC.apk");
                await CopyDownloadedFile(file, destinationPath);

                Java.IO.File apkFile = new Java.IO.File(destinationPath);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);

                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
                {
                    Android.Net.Uri apkURI = AndroidX.Core.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, "com.companyname.bingowmc.fileprovider", apkFile);
                    intent.SetDataAndType(apkURI, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    //intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                    intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraNotUnknownSource, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                }

                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
                OnUpdateStatusChanged(new UpdateStatusEventArgs(UpdateStatusEventArgs.UpdateStatusType.Completed, "Update installed successfully"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnUpdateStatusChanged(new UpdateStatusEventArgs(UpdateStatusEventArgs.UpdateStatusType.Failed, ex.Message));
            }
        }
```

Is someone see what's wrong ?

I've tried solution proposed in these topics to write the code I have :
[Xamarin app for updating apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64678630/xamarin-app-for-updating-apk-programmatically)

[Xamarin Android App update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173054/xamarin-android-app-update)

[Xamarin, Update existing app from within the app. Without any services. App not installed error when updating. Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68985243/xamarin-update-existing-app-from-within-the-app-without-any-services-app-not)

[How to make Xamarin Forms App Auto-Updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421242/how-to-make-xamarin-forms-app-auto-updated)

But I guess it's still missing something.

Comment: Make sure both apps are signed by the same key/certificate. And make sure the versionCode entry in AndroidManifest.xml of the update APK is higher than the one of the installed app.

Comment: Hello @Robert. I have only one keystore, so in the "Signing Identity" window, I always choose the same key. In my AndroidManifest.xml, I changed android:versionCode="1" to android:versionCode="2" between the two versions. Note that I can update the application by clicking on the downloaded APK.

Comment: Debug mode uses debug key, you can try to use release mode to run the version1 and version2 projects.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that both were already in release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; I just have to wait, and everything is fine. The corrected code is:

```
private async Task InstallApk(IDownloadFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            string destinationPath = GetLocalDownloadPathFromFileName("BingoWMC.apk");
            await CopyDownloadedFile(file, destinationPath);

            Java.IO.File apkFile = new Java.IO.File(destinationPath);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
            {
                Android.Net.Uri apkURI = AndroidX.Core.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, "com.companyname.bingowmc.fileprovider", apkFile);
                intent.SetDataAndType(apkURI, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                //intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraNotUnknownSource, true);
            }
            else
            {
                intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            }

            await Task.Delay(5000);
            //Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            });
            await Task.Delay(5000);

            OnUpdateStatusChanged(new UpdateStatusEventArgs(UpdateStatusEventArgs.UpdateStatusType.Completed, "Update installed successfully"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Utils.ShowErrorPopup(ex.Message);
            OnUpdateStatusChanged(new UpdateStatusEventArgs(UpdateStatusEventArgs.UpdateStatusType.Failed, ex.Message));
        }
    }
```